# How to insert sort through swap or through pop() - insert()?

Tags: python, sorting, insert, insertion-sort

I've made my own version of insertion sort that uses pop and insert - to pick out the current element and insert it before the smallest element larger than the current one - rather than the standard swapping backwards until a larger element is found. When I run the two on my computer, mine is about 3.5 times faster. When we did it in class, however, mine was much slower, which is really confusing. Anyway, here are the two functions:

```
def insertionSort(alist):
    for x in range(len(alist)):
        for y in range(x,0,-1):
            if alist[y]<alist[y-1]:
                alist[y], alist[y-1] = alist[y-1], alist[y]
            else:
                break

def myInsertionSort(alist):
    for x in range(len(alist)):
       for y in range(x):
            if alist[y]>alist[x]:
                alist.insert(y,alist.pop(x))
                break
```

Which one should be faster? Does `alist.insert(y,alist.pop(x))` change the size of the `list` back and forth, and how does that affect time efficiency?

Here's my quite primitive test of the two functions:

```
from time import time
from random import shuffle

listOfLists=[]
for x in range(100):
    a=list(range(1000))
    shuffle(a)
    listOfLists.append(a)

start=time()
for i in listOfLists:
    myInsertionSort(i[:])
myInsertionTime=time()-start

start=time()
for i in listOfLists:
    insertionSort(i[:])
insertionTime=time()-start

print("regular:",insertionTime)
print("my:",myInsertionTime)
```

Comment: Doing insert + pop might right linear time, so the latter is actually O(n * n^2) = O(n^3) in the worst case, while the former is "only" O(1 * n^2) in the worst case. [Where the `n` and `1` are the complexities of the insert+pop and swap]. Note that saying "I tried and mine was x times faster" is *useless*, because you run the code with a particular input, while efficiency is about "global performances" that hold for all inputs or for a certain class of inputs.

Comment: Have you tested your version with larger lists? Shuffle the list too: `test = range(1000); random.shuffle(test); copy1, copy2 = test, test[:]`, then feed `copy1` and `copy2` to your functions to compare them.

Comment: Also note that the difference is *not* only the swap vs insert+pop, but also the order in which you do the operations. The `y` are iterated in reverse order in the two functions this might affect performance (think about it: normal insertion sort has best case when data is sorted and worst case when the data is sorted backwards, so reversing elements *does* change the efficiency of the algorithm. comparing the two functions on the same input might *not* be a "fair" comparison, since the input might be worst case for one and not-worst-case for the other)

Comment: Martin Pieters: I've tried several times, letting each function sort copies of each list in a larger list containing 100 shuffled 1000-element-lists; and mine is always about 3 times faster.

Bakuriu: I hadn't thought of your last point. The best-case scenario of the "standard" method is actually the worst-case-scenario of my method and vice versa. But sholdn't repeated tests like the one I mentioned above eliminate that problem? I didn't quite get your firs point though. What do you mean by "Doing insert + pop might right linear time"? And why does the pop and insert have n complexity?

Comment: Disregard my above comment. I've answered Bakuriu by his post below.

Answer (score 2):

I had underestimated your question, but it actually isn't easy to answer. There are a lot of different elements to consider.

1. Doing `lst.insert(y, lst.pop(x))` is a `O(n)` operation, because `lst.pop(x)` costs `O(len(lst) - x)` since list elements must be contiguous, and thus the list has to shift-left by one all the elements after index `x`, and dually `lst.insert(y, _)` costs `O(len(lst) - y)` since it has to shift all the elements right by one.

   This means that a naive analysis can give an upperbound of O(n^3) complexity in the worst case for your code. As you suggested this is actually correct [remember that O(n^2) is a *subset* of O(n^3)], however it's not a *tight* upperbound because you swap each element only once. So for `n` times you do `n` work, and this complexity is indeed O(n * n + n^2) = O(n^2), where the second n^2 refers to the number of comparisons which is n^2 in the worst case. So, asymptotically your solution is the same as insertion sort.
2. The first algorithm and the second algorithm change the order of iterations over the `y`. As I have already commented this *changes the worst-case* for the algorithm.
    While insertion sort has its worst-case with reverse-sorted sequences, your algorithm doesn't (which is actually good). This *might* be a factor that adds to the difference in timings since if you do *not* use random lists you might use an input that is worst-case for one algorithm but not worst-case for the other.

   ```
   In [2]: %timeit insertionSort(list(range(10)))
   100000 loops, best of 3: 5.46 us per loop

   In [3]: %timeit myInsertionSort(list(range(10)))
   100000 loops, best of 3: 8.47 us per loop

   In [4]: %timeit insertionSort(list(reversed(range(10))))
   10000 loops, best of 3: 20.4 us per loop

   In [5]: %timeit myInsertionSort(list(reversed(range(10))))
   100000 loops, best of 3: 9.81 us per loop
   ```

   You should always tests with (also) random inputs with different lengths.
3. The average complexity of insertion sort is O(n^2). Your algorithm *might* have a lower average time, however it's not entirely trivial to compute it.
4. I don't get why you use the `insert+pop` at all when you can use the swap. Trying this on my machine yields a quite big improvement in efficiency since you reduce an O(n^2) component to a O(n) component.

---

Now, you ask why there was such a big change between the execution at home and in class.
There can be various reasons, for example if you did not use a random generated list you might have used an almost best-case input for insertion sort while it was an almost worst-case input for your algorithm. And similar considerations. Without seeing what you did in class is not possible to give an exact answer.

*However* I believe there is a *very* simple answer: you forgot to copy the list before profiling. This is the *same* error *I* did when I first posted this answer (quote from the previous answer):

> If you want to compare the two functions you should use *random*
>   lists:
>
> ```
> In [6]: import random
>    ...: input_list = list(range(10))
>    ...: random.shuffle(input_list)
>    ...: 
>
> In [7]: %timeit insertionSort(input_list)  # Note: no input_list[:]!! Argh!
> 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.82 us per loop
>
> In [8]: %timeit myInsertionSort(input_list)
> 100000 loops, best of 3: 7.71 us per loop
> ```
>
> Also you should use big inputs to see the difference clearly:
>
> ```
> In [11]: input_list = list(range(1000))
>     ...: random.shuffle(input_list)
>
> In [12]: %timeit insertionSort(input_list)  # Note: no input_list[:]! Argh!
> 1000 loops, best of 3: 508 us per loop
>
> In [13]: %timeit myInsertionSort(input_list)
> 10 loops, best of 3: 55.7 ms per loop
> ```

Note also that I, unfortunately, always executed the pairs of profilings in the same order, confirming my previous ideas.

As you can see all calls to `insertionSort` except the first one used a sorted list as input, which is the *best-case* for insertion-sort! This means that the timing for insertion sort is wrong (and I'm sorry for having written this before!) While `myInsertionSort` was always executed with an already sorted list, and guess what? Turns out that one of the worst-cases for `myInsertionSort` is *the sorted list*!
think about it:

```
for x in range(len(alist)):
   for y in range(x):
        if alist[y]>alist[x]:
            alist.insert(y,alist.pop(x))
            break
```

If you have a sorted list the `alist[y] > alist[x]` comparison will always be false. You might say "perfect! no swaps => no O(n) work => better timing", unfortunately this is false because no swaps also mean no `break` and hence you are doing `n*(n+1)/2` iterations, i.e. the worst-case performance.

Note that **this is very bad**!!! Real-world data *really often* is partially sorted, so an algorithm whose worst-case is the sorted list is usually *not a good algorithm* for real-world use.

Note that this does *not* change if you replace `insert + pop` with a simple swap, hence the algorithm itself is not good from this point of view, independently from the implementation.

Comment: Bakuriu: I'm very much a programming beginner, so I don't know that much about time complexity yet, but does my version really have O(n^2) swaps in worst case? In my version, each element e in the list is moved backwards at max one time, unlike in the standard version where e is moved backwards at max m times, where m is the number of elements before e. The idea behind my version is that you first find the position where to move e, and then move it all the way there, rather than swapping it backwards until the right position is found. Doesnt that make it O(n) swaps? (* n for the pop-insert)

Comment: Also, I did use random lists. I made a list containing a hundred 1000-element shuffled lists, and had both functions sort copies of those sublists.

Comment: But I don't do one swap per comparison. I pop and insert ONLY when I've found the right position for the current element; unlike in the standard version where there's one swap per comparison in worst-case. 
Look closer at your comparison with random lists. Each loop in my version takes 55.7 milliseconds and each loop in the standard version takes 508 nanoseconds. BUT the number of loops in my version is 10, while it's 1000 in the standard version. So the standard version is about (55.7*1000*10)/(508*1*1000)=ca 1.096 times faster in your test. Not 1000. Or am I completely lost here?

Comment: I've added my test in my original post, as you requested, Bakuriu.

And, oh, I might have been a bit unclear. Tecnically, I don't swap at all in my version. I just pop and insert one element.

Comment: @Moeghoeg I *heavily* edited my answer, turns out you are right in some aspects. About the `ca 1.096 times faster` you mention in the comment is *wrong*. `timeit` is a module that profile the codes executing it more times and giving as output the "average time" taken. If a function takes a lot of time to execute `timeit` automatically uses less iterations since the more time the function takes and the smaller is the error in the taking, hence less iterations are required for accurate timings. What you mentioned is the time taken to *profile* the function, which is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late reply! So in short, the two solutions should asymptotically have the same time complexity, but mine is problematic because its worst case scenario is an ordered list, so it probably isn't very useful? About the possible testing mistakes, one of those might have been made in class, but I don't think I've made any (if you look at my first post, I've updated it with my test). So there's still the mystery of why my version is much faster on my machine. Could it be that pop and insert are somehow optimized so that they're more efficient than "primitively" moving elements?

Comment: @Moeghoeg No. If you modify your algorithm to use `alist[y], alist[x] = alist[x], alist[y]` you'll see an other big increase in efficiency. The better timings are probably due to the fact that your version does `n` swaps while the original can does up to `n^2` swaps. I believe that in this case the constants hidden by the O notation matter and that's why your algorithm is a bit faster but not asymptotically faster.